# Why the build of Apache Cordova created on tfs for WP8 copied wrong icons

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, visual-studio-cordova

I have an **Apache Cordova** application with some custom icons when I build this app on local machine for WP8 all are ok. Now I try build this on **TFS2015**, build is succeeded but xap package has wrong **icons and splash screen**.

Like as default image e.g [Background.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GURpk.png)

For that I use this tutorial(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/cordova/cordova-build?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Can help me anybody with this issue?

Comment: Did you get a correct Background image in the drop location?

Comment: yes, because I checked

Answer (score 1):

When working in the CLI you can define app icon(s) via `<icon>` element (`config.xml`). If you do not specify an icon then the Apache Cordova logo is used.

Tested with an [Apache Cordova "Hello World" application](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world), if I define app icons via `<icon>` element in config.xml like the setting below:

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/wp/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
    <!-- tile image -->
    <icon src="res/wp/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />
</platform>
```

The in TFS Drop Location, I get the customized Background image.

[image]

Comment: I already have added `<icon>` element into config.xml, I tried change location of icons but without success. my icons have other size it's can be a issue?


**<platform name="wp8">    <icon src="res/wp/ApplicationIcon.png" width="60" height="60" />    <icon src="res/wp/Background.png" width="152" height="152" />  </platform>**



one things is strange why on local build it's ok?

Comment: Thnx, issue was in size

Comment: So, after changing the size of icon, the issue solved? Great.